# Allow third party users to book appointments in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

How can I allow public users to book an event in my Google calendar?

in my Business calendar that I've created in `Google Calendars` I'm allowing users to book appointments through Web app API, how can I allow my customers to book appointments directly in my calendar through the shared page, I see only busy events in the shared page and I'm restricted
to give only see events access, I tried `Microsoft Bookings` also where the slots available are publicly shown and allow users to book closest available slot, can I manage to do that in `Google Calendar`?

I've attached screen shots of Microsoft Bookings and Google Calendar shared page for reference

Google Calendar public page
[image: Google Calendar public page]

Microsoft booking public page

[image: Microsoft booking public page]